# Convert a UTC timestamp to an arbitrary timezone

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I am receiving a java.sql.Timestamp in UTC for example:

> 2014-04-03 08:25:20.0

I know, that this timestamp is in UTC. And I know that the target timezone for this timestamp.  Example:

> Europe/Berlin

Now I 'd like to convert the UTC timestmap to a localized timestamp. With the correct daylight savings, of course.

My attempt so far:

```
println(msg.timestamp)
println(new DateTime(msg.timestamp))
val storeTz = DateTimeZone.forID(store.timezone)
println(new DateTime(msg.timestamp, storeTz))
val localTimestamp = new DateTime(msg.timestamp).withZone(storeTz)
println(localTimestamp)
```

This prints:

```
2014-04-03 08:25:20.0
2014-04-03T08:25:20.000+02:00
2014-04-03T07:25:20.000+01:00
2014-04-03T07:25:20.000+01:00
```

Shouldn't the correct localized timestamp be:

```
2014-04-03T10:25:20.000+02:00
```

Comment: It says +02:00 behind. 10:00 + 02:00 would be 12:00 I think. (Notice the missing ( ) around the +02:00). So 08:00 +02:00 might already be your desired output, only wrong formated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this might work

```
println(msg.timestamp)
println(new DateTime(msg.timestamp))
val storeTz = DateTimeZone.forID(store.timezone)
println(new DateTime(msg.timestamp, storeTz))
val localTimestamp = new DateTime(msg.timestamp).withZoneRetainFields(DateTimeZone.UTC).toDateTime(storeTz)
println(localTimestamp)
```

Comment: This is close to correct. Now I am getting the localized timestamp but it seems that the current daylight saving is now taken into account. The out put is 2014-04-03T09:25:20.000+02:00

Comment: according to the [world clock](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/) this is correct. The time in Europe/Berlin differs 2 hours from UTC.

Comment: Huh? But then a fully localized timestamp should be 2014-04-03T10:25:20.000+02:00 shouldn't it?

Comment: I did this: `DateTime date = new DateTime(2014, 4, 3, 8, 25, 20, DateTimeZone.forID("UTC")); System.out.println(date.toDateTime(DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Berlin")));` and the output is 2014-04-03T10:25:20.000+02:00 so maybe you shouldn't use the convertUTCToLocal method but this instead

Comment: Can you try this with `new DateTime(1396506356000)` as well?

Comment: I see the problem now, you have to say that the timestamp is in the UTC timezone but retain the field values. Then convert to the correct timezone. See edits.

Comment: Could you explain to me what exactly `withZoneRetainFields`does?

Comment: See [JavaDoc](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withZoneRetainFields(org.joda.time.DateTimeZone))

Answer (score 0):

The other answer seems needlessly complicated. Here is my take using Joda-Time 2.3.

Berlin is 2 hours ahead of UTC because of Daylight Saving Time nonsense. So if UTC is 8 AM, then Berlin is 10 AM.

```
String inputRaw = "2014-04-03 08:25:20.0";
String input = inputRaw.replace( " ", "T" ); // Convert to strict ISO 8601 format.

DateTime dateTimeUtc = new DateTime( input, DateTimeZone.UTC );

DateTimeZone timeZoneBerlin = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Berlin" );
DateTime dateTimeBerlin = dateTimeUtc.withZone( timeZoneBerlin );
```

Dump to console…

```
System.out.println( "input: " + input );
System.out.println( "dateTimeUtc: " + dateTimeUtc );
System.out.println( "dateTimeBerlin: " + dateTimeBerlin );
```

When run…

```
input: 2014-04-03T08:25:20.0
dateTimeUtc: 2014-04-03T08:25:20.000Z
dateTimeBerlin: 2014-04-03T10:25:20.000+02:00
```